# How do I change the answers to the export compliance questions in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

How do i change the answers to the export compliance questions on iTunes Connect once I've entered them?

I don't know how to get back to that page. How do I get back to that page?

(I'm trying to publish an app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either uploading a new binary update or **rejecting** the App's actual binary and then pressing on **Ready to Upload Binary** should do the trick.

As written under Apple's [iTunes Connect Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW6):

> **Cryptography and U.S. Export Compliance**
>
> U.S. export laws require that products containing encryption be properly authorized for export. **When you’re ready to upload your first binary for your app or upload a binary update, iTunes Connect presents a series of questions regarding software encryption.** The questions are designed to determine the level of encryption in the app according to U.S. Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) classifications.

Answer (score 0):

To provide more documentation you can click on the Services Tab (next to TestFlight), then Encryption.